# The layout briefly distorts upon opening the page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

When I load the page, the layout briefly appears distorted for a moment. I'm not sure of the cause, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

ReproductionRepository: https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/tree/fix-layout-issue

ReproductionURL: https://document-driven-demo.netlify.app/ja/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: in default.vue layout you should call `handleResize` on setup, not on mounted, so the component is mounted with the correct layout.

Comment: Make a difference between the server and client visuals (can enable/disable the JS for that) + check the size of those images.

Comment: @IgorMoraru When I moved 'handleResize();' outside of 'onMounted,' it resulted in a 'window is not defined' error."

Comment: @kissu What does 'visuals' refer to? Could you provide specific context for clarification?

Comment: I suppose you are using SSR. if so, you can ignore my comment

Comment: @IgorMoraru No, this time we are taking the approach of uploading the generated files in the production environment

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `<client-only></client-only>`.