# The behavior of client-side rendering and server-side rendering in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

Currently, in `default.vue`, we are wrapping everything with `<client-only>`. If we don't do this, there is a brief moment when the page is initially displayed where the layout is still being constructed and partially visible. Why does wrapping it with `<client-only>` resolve this issue?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { inject } from 'vue';

const route = useRoute();
const { baseUrl } = useRuntimeConfig().public;
const { locale } = useI18n();
const shouldShowDrawer = ref(false);
const mobileLayout = ref(false);

const handleResize = () => {
  shouldShowDrawer.value = window.innerWidth >= 1023;
  mobileLayout.value = window.innerWidth <= 1023;
};

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  handleResize();
  console.log('mobileLayout', mobileLayout.value);
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
});

let redirectPath = route.path.endsWith('/')
  ? route.path.slice(0, -1)
  : route.path;

if (redirectPath.startsWith('/en')) {
  locale.value = 'en';
} else if (redirectPath.startsWith('/ja')) {
  locale.value = 'ja';
}

if (process.client) {
  switch (redirectPath) {
    case '':
      navigateTo(redirectPath + '/ja', { replace: true });
      break;
  }
}

let ogLocale = '';
if (redirectPath.startsWith('/ja')) {
  ogLocale = 'ja_JP';
} else if (redirectPath.startsWith('/en')) {
  ogLocale = 'en_US';
}

useSeoMeta({
  ogLocale,
  ogUrl: baseUrl + route.path,
  ogType: 'website',
  ogSiteName: '',
  ogImage: baseUrl + '/images/social-image.jpg',
  ogImageWidth: 1200,
  ogImageHeight: 627,
  ogImageType: 'image/png',
  // ogTitle: () => page.value?.head.title,
  twitterCard: 'summary_large_image',
  // twitterDescription: () => page.value?.description,
  twitterImage: baseUrl + '/images/social-image.jpg',
  twitterSite: '',
  // twitterTitle: () => page.value?.head.title,
});
const mobileDrawer = ref(false);
watch(mobileDrawer, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  console.log('mobileDrawer changed from', oldVal, 'to', newVal);
});
function handleMobileDrawerClicked(newValue: boolean) {
  mobileDrawer.value = newValue;
  console.log('変更');
}
</script>

<template>
  <client-only>
    <v-app>
      <div v-if="mobileDrawer" class="responsive-side-menu-wrapper">
        <ResponsiveSideMenu></ResponsiveSideMenu>
      </div>
      <Header
        :mobileDrawer="mobileDrawer"
        @mobileDrawerClicked="handleMobileDrawerClicked"
      />

      <div class="responsive-toc-wrapper" v-if="mobileLayout">
        <ResponsiveTableOfContents></ResponsiveTableOfContents>
      </div>
      <v-container>
        <div class="d-flex flex-0-1-100">
          <SideMenu v-if="shouldShowDrawer" />
          <v-main
            class="pl-0 pr-0 flex-shrink-1"
            :class="{ 'v-main-border': !mobileLayout }"
          >
            <slot />
            <NavigationLink />
          </v-main>
          <TableofContents v-if="shouldShowDrawer" />
        </div>
      </v-container>
      <Footer />
    </v-app>
  </client-only>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
.v-main-border {
  border-left: 1px solid $border-color-gray;
  border-right: 1px solid $border-color-gray;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
}
// headerの背景色はresponsive-toc-wrapperのbackground-colorに設定されている
header {
  position: sticky !important;
  backdrop-filter: saturate(200%) blur(20px);
}
@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  header {
    background: none !important;
  }
}
.responsive-side-menu-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1100;
  height: 100%;
}
.responsive-toc-wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 64px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: $bg-color-white !important;
  backdrop-filter: saturate(200%) blur(20px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color-gray;
}
.v-navigation-drawer {
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

The following site reflects the code when it is not wrapped with `<client-only>` :

https://document-driven-demo.netlify.app/ja/getting-started/introduction/

ReproductionRepository: https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site

Comment: Nuxt by default uses SSR/SSG, so the content is generated on the server before being hydrated on the client. The purpose for that can be performance + SEO. If you don't care about this, use your Nuxt app as SPA-only (like a default Vue app). If you do want the isomorphic approach (server + client), you will need to troubleshoot a few things to make it run smoothly on both ends.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77139452/8816585) is not a solution then. If you want to see where this comes from, try to disable JS (you will see the server part).

Comment: @kissu
why does content briefly appear without the layout when it should be generated with SSR? I'm not sure why this happens. Could it be due to certain Vuetify components not being compatible with SSR?

Comment: There could be a good of reasons for that but yeah, Vuetify is not perfect in that regard as far as I know. Use your devtools/console and fiddle with JS (enabled/disabled) to find out more.

Comment: @kissu
Thank you. I tried disabling JavaScript in the developer tools, and it stayed in the state before the layout was completed. However, in that case, is there no solution to this issue other than using ``<client-only>``?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question here. Do you need SSR at all to begin with?

Comment: @kissu
I also had some doubts about that. But to begin with, why does "npm run generate" involve SSR and CSR?

Comment: Because you usually reach out to Nuxt when you need SSR/SSG. You can opt out from it if you want SPA-only: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#rendering-modes